# Convert year.week to date

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I have times in the format YYYY.week:

```
x <- c("2016.49", "2016.50", "2016.51", "2016.52", "2017.01", "2017.02", "2017.03", "2017.04", "2017.05")
```

Is there a way to create the convert it to date variables like this (date is not true, but that's the desired format):

```
as.Date(x[1])
"2017-02-01"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you append a weekday then `as.Date` will work:

```
x <- c("2016.49", "2016.50", "2016.51")

as.Date(paste0(x, ".1"), "%Y.%U.%u")

[1] "2016-12-05" "2016-12-12" "2016-12-19"
```

Answer (score 2):

One `lubridate` option could be:

```
ymd(paste0(substr(x, 1, 4), "-01", "-01"))+weeks(as.numeric(substr(x, nchar(x)-1, nchar(x)))-1)

 [1] "2016-12-02" "2016-12-09" "2016-12-16" "2016-12-23" "2017-01-01"
```

Sample data:

```
x <- c("2016.49", "2016.50", "2016.51", "2016.52", "2017.01")
```

Comment: thank you very much, clever solution, but the other one is a bit easier :)

Answer (score 2):

One more `lubridate` option

```
parse_date_time(paste0(x,'.Mon'),'Y/W/a')
[1] "2016-12-05 UTC" "2016-12-12 UTC" "2016-12-19 UTC" "2016-12-26 UTC" "2017-01-02 UTC"
```